# error: too many arguements to function

Tags: c++

I am writing in C++ and I got an error about

> declaration of 'triangle' as multidimensional array must have bounds for all dimensions except the first

I have a function that looks like the following one:

```
int func( int height, int row, int check, int triangle[][]) {
    // some code
}
```

And I have a code below that goes like this:

```
int main(){
    int small, big;

    if( func( height, x, 0, triangle)>big){
         small = big;
         big = func( height, x, 0, triangle);
     }
}
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Show us more code and the exact error message.

Comment: Please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us instead. Also, when posting questions about errors, please include the complete and unedited error message in the question body.

Comment: The error message seems crystal clear to me. What is now unclear? You have to specify bounds for all dimensions except the first, but you put two unbounded dimensions.

Answer (score 3):

You can use this way...

```
template <typename TwoD>
int func(int height,int row, int check, TwoD& triangle){
}
```

TwoD work with all two dimensional array type data structure ,example

```
vector<vector<T>>
```

or a user defined type to maximize code reuse.

Comment: If this solution works for you please mark this as solved. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

When you are using multidimensional array as function argument you have to define its size - without defining first one. So for example:

```
    int func(int height,int row, int check, int triangle[][2]) //here second size has been defined with 2
    {
        //whatever
        return 2; //just for test
    }

    int main()
    {
        int height = 1, x = 2;
        int triangle[2][2]; //defined size must accord to the defined one - the first can be anything here

        if( func(height,x,0,triangle) > 1 )
        {
            //do something
        }
    }
```